# Include posters from conferences in Customized CurVe CV

Tags: biblatex, cv

I have a question about this template: (https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv)

Currently, I can include articles, books and conference proceedings in the "Research publications" sections by adding `@ARTICLE`, `@BOOK` or `@INPROCEEDINGS`. This works fine. Now, I want to include my contributions to international conferences such as posters in this way:

1. Title: Title of the poster goes here
2. Authors: Authors of the poster (same way than in an article)
3. Congress name: 1th International Conference on ...
4. Place and date: London (UK), July, 1-2, 2023
5. Organizer: University of whatever
6. Character: International

*(List numbers are not necessary)*

Would that modification in the code be possible? My idea is to include this information in this style:

```
@POSTER{123456789,
  author={...},
  title={...}, 
  year={...},
...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You have tagged `biblatex`, can you confirm that is the bib packaage you are using and not `natbib` or `bibtex` please. That looks possible, you may want to look at the `biblatex-cv` package here that might already contain what you want: https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-cv?lang=en

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but according to the template (https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv) the bib package is biblatex

Comment: Just for the record: The current template seems to use the IEEE BibLaTeX style: `\PassOptionsToPackage{style=ieee,sorting=ydnt,uniquename=init,defernumbers=true}{biblatex}`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!